# installing moveIt - on jade ubuntu 15.04

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install moveIt on jade on ubuntu 15.04. I have been following the method presented in [this](http://moveit.ros.org/install/). At step 2 & 3: ROS JADE (particularly on step 3) when I run the following command

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y
```

I receive errors such as

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-warehouse-ros
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-jade-warehouse-ros] failed
```

This was the folder, which was not being downloaded by the given address. So, to resolve this problem, I manually downloaded zip file from this cite ([cite](https://github.com/ros-planning/warehouse_ros)) and copied extracted files in my moveit/src directory. After that, when I run command

```
catkin_make
```

I get this error

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
MongoDB_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
   used as include directory in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
   used as include directory in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
   used as include directory in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
   used as include directory in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
   used as include directory in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
   used as include directory in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
   used as include directory in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
MongoDB_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "warehouse_ros" in directory /home/khan/moveit/src/warehouse_ros
```

Seeing this, I tried to download the warehouse file from this cite ([cite](https://github.com/TheBrewCrew?tab=repositories)). I did not get above error after running catkin_make but I had another error which is

```
make[2]: *** [moveit_plugins/moveit_ros_control_interface/CMakeFiles/moveit_ros_control_interface_plugin.dir/src/controller_manager_plugin.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Please, help me out. How can I remove this error. I shall buy cookies for you. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226882/installing-moveit---on-jade-ubuntu-15.04/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
I think it would be a good idea to actually include the errors that you get when running `rosdep`.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-02-17**:
I have edited the question and included the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> At step 2 & 3: ROS JADE (particularly on step 3) when I run the following command

> ```
> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y
> ```

The instructions you link to seem to use `indigo` for the `--rosdistro` option:

> STEP 3: Make sure MoveIt! dependencies are installed

> ```
> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
> ```

I haven't used those instructions myself, but apparently that should work for Jade.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-02-17**:
In case, an apt-get release is not available for the system, if you install from source, some of the dependencies might also not be available. In that case, use the --deps and --exclude options from rosinstall_generator.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-02-17**:
I have tried this method but again stuck with errors. I guess, I need to shift back to indigo, it is better.